# LOAD DATA INFILE does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running **MySQL** on my **Ubuntu** machine. I checked `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, it shows my database temporary directory:

```
...
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
...
```

As it shows, my MySQL server temporary directory is `/tmp` .

I have a `students.dat` file, the content of this file is like following:

```
...
30  kate    name
31  John    name
32  Bill    name
33  Job     name
...
```

I copied the above `students.dat` file to `/tmp` directory. Then, I run the following command to load the data from `students.dat` file to the **students** table in my database:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/students.dat'
            INTO TABLE school_db.students
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
            (student_id, name, attribute)
```

But I got the error message in MySQL console:

```
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/tmp/students.dat' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

**Why mysql can not find** the `students.dat` file **though the file is under mysql temporary directory?**

**P.S.**

The **students** table is like following (there are already 4 records in the table before run the `LOAD DATA INFILE...` query):

```
mysql> describe students;

    +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | student_id        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | name              | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | attribute         | varchar(12)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | teacher_id        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the sixth post from [file not found error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=822084). It seems if you specify `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` should work (They added the `LOCAL` keyword)

Comment: `LOCAL INFILE` is a workaround. A solution to use it as is might be to change the file ownership to that of `mysql`.  Alternatively, I have two installs of the same MySQL server and client, and one supports a regular `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Only difference is that MySQL's `/var/lib/mysql` is on a different partition from `/tmp/`

Answer (score 2):

`ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/tmp/file_name' not found (Errcode: 13)`

This error occurs mainly when we try to load data file from any location to any table in mysql database.

Just change the owner of a file.

1) Check permissions of the file with this command:
    `ls -lhrt <filename>`

2) Then change ownership:
    `chown mysql.mysql <filename>`

3) Now try `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.  It will work.