# Load data from txt file using PHP Form

Tags: php, mysql, load

I am trying to load data from txt file (| separated) using simple php form. Bellow is the code :

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."'
INTO TABLE asn_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 2 LINES
";
```

But when I browse the file and submit it shows following error:

```
File '/tmp/phpkR9fXW' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

If I change the syntax to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` it provides following error:
    The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

My PHP version is 5.3.10, MySQL Version 5.5 and OS is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

I have tried solution given in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=822084 but no luck.

Comment: Could be related, sice we are talking about ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile

Comment: Have you tried adding the `LOCAL` keyword into `LOAD DATA INFILE` 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471727/load-data-infile-does-not-work (also mentioned in the linked thread)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a very similar problem and it turned out to be a permissions issue where the MySQL server couldn't open the file.

[The MySQL Doc's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html) has some useful information on the issue.