# SQL query and temporary file permissions

Tags: php, html, mysql, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import a .csv file in a MySQL database using HTML/PHP. The code is:

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  File: <input type="file" name="csv"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Send" name="subCSV">
</form>
```

PHP

```
$file = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"];

try {
  $query = $connexion -> prepare("LOAD DATA INFILE ? into TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS");
  $query->bindValue(1, $file, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); $errorCode = $e->getCode();
```

But I'm getting that error:

```
File '/tmp/phpl8eY59' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

Specifying the file explicitly works. The permissions are fine, the user running Apache and the file owner are identical. I have granted file permission on the database user.

Apparently configuring AppArmor would solve the problem, but I'm not using it, as it is not installed on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with this:

```
chmod($file, 0644);
```

The Apache/PHP user and the MySQL user were not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE". See eg the answer here: [LOAD DATA INFILE does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471727/load-data-infile-does-not-work). The problem is that there seem to be various causes of this problem.